# Как исключить русские буквы из java кода и sql

Tags: java, sql

Есть проект в котором все пишется на английском, но иногда в sql liquabase и java коде попадаются русские буквы. Есть ли какой то способ в IDEA или Maven или другой инструмент для нахождения таких не английских букв и валиться с ошибкой компиляции.

Comment: в Idea есть поиск по regexp. Просто указываете интервал русских букв, выбираете расширение файла -- и Idea найдет все совпадения. Разумеется, их можно и заменить через Idea. Другой вариант -- обычный grep, тут даже Idea не нужна.
По поводу "валиться с ошибкой компиляции" -- тут можно просто сканировать все файлы проекта на наличие таких букв. Но это несколько кастыльно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о комментариях, то способ описан в комментарии от @Mikhaillonkin

Если речь идет об идентификаторах в Java - то тут немного проще. В норме, идентификаторы всегда из символов ASCII, однако, поддерживаются идентификаторы в Unicode, например можно написать:

```
int мояПеременная=1;
```

правда надо указать тогда флажок в компиляторе/IDE: `javac -encoding <code>` - указать кодовую страницу в которой заданы идентификаторы.

Отсюда и решение - убрать этот флажок компилятора/IDE и сразу на все русские идентификаторы вывалится ворох ошибок компилятора.

В Intellij IDEA настройка флажка делается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]